# Binary File read in Google Dataflow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I  need to read binary file in google dataflow , 
I just need to read file and parse every 64 byte as one record and apply some logic in each byte of every 64 byte of binary file in dataflow.

same thing I tried in spark , code smape as  belows:

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .appName("RecordSplit")
      .master("local[*]")
      .getOrCreate()

    val df = spark.sparkContext.binaryRecords("< binary-file-path>", 64)

    val Table = df.map(rec => {
      val c1= (convertHexToString(rec(0)))
      val c2= convertBinaryToInt16(rec, 48)
      val c3= rec(59)
      val c4= convertHexToString(rec(50)) match {
        case str =>
          if (str.startsWith("c"))
            2020 + str.substring(1).toInt
          else if (str.startsWith("b"))
            2010 + str.substring(1).toInt
          else if (str.startsWith("b"))
            2000 + str.substring(1).toInt
        case _ => 1920
      }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

It is better to show what is actually happening, rather than describing what you expect to happen.

Please include code and output as content for your question, not as pictures or external links.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following:

- If you are not limited to python/scala, [OffsetBasedSource](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/OffsetBasedSource.html) (FileBasedSource is a subclass) can address your needs because it uses offsets to define the starting and ending positions.
- [TikaIO](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.3.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) can process metadata, however it can read binary data as per documentation.
- The example [dataflow-opinion-analysis](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-opinion-analysis/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/opinionanalysis/io/RecordFileSource.java) contains information to read from arbitrary byte position.
- There are additional docs to create a custom [Read implementation](https://beam.apache.org/contribute/runner-guide/#implementing-the-read-primitive). You may want to consider looking at these [Beam examples](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/testing/#examples) for guidance on how to implement a custom source, like this [python example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/python-custom-io/).

A different approach would be making arrays of 64 bytes outside pipeline (in-memory) and then creating a [PCollection from memory](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Create.html), just keep in mind that documentation recommends it for unit tests.

Comment: You could also do this as an SplittableDoFn, or (assuming you have enough files to get the required parallelism) with FileIO.match() followed by a DoFn that reads through the file emitting 64-byte chunks. (This latter solution won't provide as good splitting behavior as using OffsetBasedSource, but might be much quicker to write up.)