# Reading GPKG format file over Apache Beam

Tags: python, gis, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a requirement to parse and load `gpgk` extension file to Bigquery table through apache beam (Dataflow runner). I could see that beam has feature called [Geobeam](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-python/), but i couldn't see reference for loading of  `gpgk` files.

Q1: Which Beam library can help me to load `geopakage` file?
Q2: As an alternate solution i am trying to read `geopakage` file as Binary file and over `ParDo` can transform it and get it loaded. How we can read `Binary` file over Apache beam?

Does any one has experience over the same and share experience.

***Update: Alternate solution***
I have a requirement to read Binary Coded file through Python Apache beam  (Dataflow as a runner).

I am trying to replicate following [example](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/developing-io-python/) `Reading from a new Source` over my code to read Binary files.

My code looks is given below, can you help me where its going wrong:-

```
#------------Import Lib-----------------------#
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions, StandardOptions
import apache_beam as beam, os, sys, argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions
from apache_beam.io import iobase

#------------Set up BQ parameters-----------------------#
project = 'proj-dev'
dataset_id = 'sandbox'
table_schema_Audit = ('id:STRING,name:STRING')
input = 'gs://bucket/beers.csv'
BUCKET = 'bucket'

#-------------Splitting Of Records----------------------#
class Transaction(iobase.BoundedSource):
    def process(self):
        # Open the Shapefile
        import fiona
        with fiona.open('gs://bucket/2022_data.gpkg', 'r') as input_file:
            parsed_data = [[{"id": json.loads(json.dumps(feature['properties']))['Id'],
                        "name": json.loads(json.dumps(feature['properties']))['Name']}] for feature in input_file]
        return parsed_data

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    pipeline_args = [
      '--project={0}'.format(project),
      '--job_name=loadstructu',
      '--staging_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--temp_location=gs://{0}/staging/'.format(BUCKET),
      '--region=us-yyyy1',
      '--runner=DataflowRunner',
      '--subnetwork=https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/proj-dev/regions/us-yyyy1/subnetworks/xxxxxx-dev-subnet'
    ]

    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session
    p1 = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)

    data_loading = (
        p1
        | 'ReadData' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(Transaction())   
        )

#---------------------Type = load----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    result = (
    data_loading
        | 'Write-Audit' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                                    table='structdata',
                                                    dataset=dataset_id,
                                                    project=project,
                                                    schema=table_schema_Audit,
                                                    create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                                    write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE
                                                    ))

    result = p1.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  run()
```

It popping error as given below:-

```
~/apache-beam-2.43.0/packages/beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py in __init__(self, file_pattern, min_bundle_size, compression_type, strip_trailing_newlines, coder, validate, skip_header_lines, delimiter, escapechar, **kwargs)
    772         skip_header_lines=skip_header_lines,
    773         delimiter=delimiter,
--> 774         escapechar=escapechar)
    775 
    776   def expand(self, pvalue):

~/apache-beam-2.43.0/packages/beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/textio.py in __init__(self, file_pattern, min_bundle_size, compression_type, strip_trailing_newlines, coder, buffer_size, validate, skip_header_lines, header_processor_fns, delimiter, escapechar)
    133         min_bundle_size,
    134         compression_type=compression_type,
--> 135         validate=validate)
    136 
    137     self._strip_trailing_newlines = strip_trailing_newlines

~/apache-beam-2.43.0/packages/beam/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/filebasedsource.py in __init__(self, file_pattern, min_bundle_size, compression_type, splittable, validate)
    110           '%s: file_pattern must be of type string'
    111           ' or ValueProvider; got %r instead' %
--> 112           (self.__class__.__name__, file_pattern))
    113 
    114     if isinstance(file_pattern, str):

TypeError: _TextSource: file_pattern must be of type string or ValueProvider; got <__main__.Transaction object at 0x7fcc79ffc250> instead
```

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements and what you mean by processing of process gpkg files.

Comment: Hello, I have updated my post with more detail requirements.

Comment: Does this [stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52762294/binary-file-read-in-google-dataflow) help you?

Comment: I am trying to do similar but see some challenge. I have also updated my post with error. Can you see some improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution which worked for me is by adding following 2 additional functions before running beam pipelines :-

```
#-------------convert binary file to a txt file----------------------#
def file_create():
        # Open the Shapefile
        import fiona, json
        f = open("data.txt", "a")
        with fiona.open('gs://bucket/2022_data.gpkg', 'r') as input_file:
            for feature in input_file:
                row = json.loads(json.dumps(feature['properties']))['Id'] + ';' + json.loads(json.dumps(feature['properties']))['Name'] + ';' + str(shape(json.loads(json.dumps(feature['geometry'])))) +'\n'
                f.write(row)
        f.close()

#---------------Upload newly created file to GCS-------------------------
def upload():
    client = storage.Client()
    bucket = client.bucket('bucket')
    blob = bucket.blob('data.txt')
    blob.upload_from_filename('data.txt')
```